# (Visual Studio) How can I use googletest libs and headers from outside my solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, googletest

I'm using the built-in Google Test Adapter to write unit tests for a project in Visual Studio 2017. When I create the unit test project in my solution VS creates a package directory with the libs and header files for googletest, along with a package.config file. However I'd like to keep the googletest files out of my solution directory (and source control, though obviously I could just ignore them), and in a shared directory like the windows or standard library headers.

How can I configure my solution to get the libs and header files from a shared directory outside of my solution?

Comment: May one inquire why you wish to keep the tests (and their sources) out of the solution? Usually it is advantagous to be able to simply "deploy" the entire project from Source Contol, and have the complete package - tests and all - ready to go (i.e. to be built and run). Plus having tests under source control helps you quite a bit keepin them synced up with the project (e.g. you make a change in a feature branch which causes some tests to break - not due to a bug, but because the expected result changed; if you change the tests they will fail on master until you merge the feature branch back)

Comment: Not tests, but the test library. There's no reason for the test library to be in my source control, googletest already has it's own source control, it would just be bloat to mine.

Regardless, I learned that the recommended way in Visual Studio is just to leave the library packages in the solution directory but exclude them from source control, and rely on NuGet to automatically download the packages when cloning the project. This is satisfactory for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite the answer I was looking for, but I learned that Visual Studio can automatically download NuGet packages when they are missing from solutions. Therefor you can just ignore the package directory from your source control but include packages.config, and whenever you clone the project Visual Studio will download the missing packages. This was good enough for my needs.